# Best way to build data frame from nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

After processing the data I have saved group level calculations in following structure (Nested Dictionary):

```
{'Source1': {(1, 2): {'value1': -1.4089917877152731, 'value2': 0.15890127107708821}, (1, 3): {'value1': -3.6436438771179183, 'value2': 0.00027189114106343325}, (1, 4): {'value1': 1.3921379718956783, 'value2': 0.1639443047264573}, (2, 3): {'value1': -2.1272739953077449, 'value2': 0.033444556519261023}, (3, 4): {'value1': 5.0887284442498775, 'value2': 3.7318559307126006e-07}, (2, 4): {'value1': 2.781268059718232, 'value2': 0.0054326884405563099}}, 'Source2': {(1, 2): {'value1': 1.6065065530210021, 'value2': 0.10840303417258132}, (1, 3): {'value1': -0.67561007794063666, 'value2': 0.49941051115943469}, (1, 4): {'value1': -0.99500921260852215, 'value2': 0.31991568858488023}, (2, 3): {'value1': -2.4076869756909676, 'value2': 0.016168545874782416}, (3, 4): {'value1': -0.31851460166510093, 'value2': 0.75013768971795858}, (2, 4): {'value1': -2.7976881039916965, 'value2': 0.0052043800033575345}}}
```

Structure of the dictionary is:

```
Level1 - Source
Level2 - Group comparison (1,2) means compare Group 1 vs Group2
Level3 - Value of the comparison in two measurement types
```

My goal is to obtain following table

```
Source Name | (1,2) | (1,3) | (1,4) | ......| (2,4)|
Source1 | value1 | value1 | ................| value1
```

- I think including value 2 is somewhat impossilbe so ignore the value2

Whats the best way to convert this into a pandas data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df = pd.concat({k:pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in d.items()})
df.columns = ['({},{})'.format(i,j) for i,j in df.columns]
print (df)
                   (1,2)     (1,3)     (1,4)     (2,3)     (2,4)         (3,4)
Source1 value1 -1.408992 -3.643644  1.392138 -2.127274  2.781268  5.088728e+00
        value2  0.158901  0.000272  0.163944  0.033445  0.005433  3.731856e-07
Source2 value1  1.606507 -0.675610 -0.995009 -2.407687 -2.797688 -3.185146e-01
        value2  0.108403  0.499411  0.319916  0.016169  0.005204  7.501377e-01
```

Comment: writing to csv i set up index to false to get the souce column and value column. how do i include header for those two columns.

Comment: If want write to csv also index values with header use `df.rename_axis(('a','b')).reset_index().to_csv(file, index=False)`.